# Hype compromises effort

Tags: discussion, up-votes

Recently I have been noticing a trend in the types of questions that are upvoted. I have concluded that questions that seem to be tough(tough in this context means that many users are not able to solve it) and effortless tend to get more upvotes than questions with "clear,useful research and effort".

Consider [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3924758/734160) recent question. The OP has made no effort other than merely sharing a "thought". Also consider [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54506/734160) and even [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12906/734160).

While posts with at least some effort posted by new users are brutally downvoted and closed(as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3923763/734160) case), others with a lot of effort put in are poorly received, and sometimes left unanswered/abandoned.

I do believe that intriguing questions are to be upvoted for some attention. However, "effort put in" should be the decisive factor for upvoting a question. How can the community resolve this issue?

Comment: As of the old questions you linked, the community standards and guidelines 10 years ago were different. **in my opinion**, if a question looks like "If you put a nail there, it will work" tend to get less attention than "can you balance nails on top of each other?" and "I don't know how to hammer a nail". This is an attribute to the human nature, i.e. sharing the most possible.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "Hype" in your title?

Comment: Try to write a more relevant title, rather than a click-bait-ish title.

Comment: The post that was "brutally downvoted and closed" looked like this when it was first posted: Group homomorphism mappings between different types of group

How does one work out which elements map from say <Z/nZ,+> to say Sn if theta(1) = some permutation of Sn for example?
So, not much effort there. I expect it was the editing that led to it being reopened.

Comment: I recently got a question closed via CURED chatroom. It was a recent question from Nov 2020 and was at a very advanced level (for me at least) and had no context whatsoever. It was well received and well answered before it came in my review queue (via audit). I hope this will encourage askers to add some context in questions which are at an advanced level or rather difficult / tough. Not everyone may share this view but I think treating such questions in a different manner leads to double standards.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I hope the same too. I just want this to be a harmonious give-and-take community(as always ;-)).

Comment: @DatBoi: the community is mostly harmonious. There may be some rare events which may lead to a different perception, but for this site I find people and their behavior much nicer than what I see elsewhere (online and offline).

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing is that most people find it easier to advise on standard methods/ textbook answers rather than spend time to think through and write a tailored response to someone who is having a particular doubt.

In my personal experience, there are some particular people who attend those types of conceptual questions particularly but those people generally seek out a high standard of such questions and reply rarely.

A final note is  appealing questions are preferred over ~~ non-appealing one.

Edit: replaced the word exciting with appealing

---

Personal anecdotes of this:

My top most answer is one where I gave a one-line solution to a determinant problem , [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3847415/matrix-with-given-condition-abcd-0/3847417#3847417) vs this [detailed answer I wrote](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3877931/688539)

Comment: How would you define "exciting questions"?  Only those questions that excite you personally?  Ditto for your definition of "non-exciting questions"  (those that do not excite you)?

Comment: Well it's not from a personal standpoint rather the collective 'emergent' mind which represents the community. There are questions about certain topics which people on this site find more appealing than others.

Comment: It is rather ludicrous for any one user (here only one year and a couple of months)  to claim they are speaking on behalf of "the emergent mind which represents the community, particularly given the thousands of users who've been here far longer than you. One year and a couple of months on this site doesn't bestow the privilege of assuming you know what the 'emergent' mind representing the community, would say.

Comment: Also, Buraian, you never answered questions.  what counts as "exciting questions" and "non-exciting questions"?

Comment: Disregarding the amount of time that I was here, it is a fact that a collective consciousness exists for this site whether you like it or not, we are all simply nodes in the  'brain' of this site. I'm not speaking as a spokes person for it, but rather my opinion on what it is backed by my personal experience. Your personal experience may differ leading you to a different conclusions.

I think that the true answer to this question is subjective and varies from person to person unless we do some sort of statistical studies on the different kinds of questions asked.

Comment: Whatever the community wishes it to be, there are simply more preference for certain kind of question and answers than others

Comment: Thanks for acknowleging this question, and your answer are opinion-based/subjective.  And that's a reason for closure.

Comment: Well isn't most of meta answers , a collective opinion of the stackexchange community? There is no absolute bible where we can derive policy from rather it is done best to the knowledge of the crowd

Comment: Regarding your second-to-last comment: perhaps but those preferences of some often counter the preferences of others.   And  all I'm asking is for you to assert you know precisely what the collective will of this site is.  Hence, do not answer any questions on main, or on meta, by subjective speculation.

Comment: I am not sure how you are so confidently saying there is some objective truths which can be written as answers. The only truth in science is a collective agreement, not an absolute one.

Comment: And may I remind you, you have failed to answer my questions posed at the start.

Comment: You are barraging me with questions, let's work through them one by one

Comment: You're putting words in my mouth, in your current second-to-last comment.  I said nothing to the effect you are claiming I said.  No, you keep evading answering my initial questions.  I don't play games with users who interact by playing games.

Comment: Ok, maybe miscommunication but I am not understanding what you are saying. You are saying not to answer any question by subjective speculation, to that I answer most of science involves collective agreement rather than some objective truth. I simply gave me subjective view point on this matter on meta. It's impossible for anyone to give any sort of objective answer on this, if you think it is possible then please explain how

Comment: I'll post some examples of what I mean to illustrate my point

Comment: Simple answer for the what is collective opinion thing:  Whatever the average person in using this site finds interesting, it's an emergent property which a single individual can never say.

Comment: How would you define "the average person using this site"?  You think you know these things, but in fact, as you've very clearly displayed, you can't pin anything you claim or refer to or appeal to.  Every one of your attempts at defining, is more and more subjective.  Your answer and responses are circular.

Comment: You're literally asking me to give a way to say what the users of the site like, that's impossible to do. all i am saying is there is a notion of prefarance among those who use the site. The only way to answer such a question is through statistics

Comment: Buraian, Martin Sleziak has done many site analysis' , particularly about closed or not-well received questions/answers. You might want to check them for the stats. It's a 20K + stat analysis and not Data SEDE one.